# How to remove quotation list in python

Tags: python

I have a list like this 
`['1000', '6', '1', '5', '14', '34', '43', '3', '18', '28', '16']`
 I want like this 
`[1000, 6, 1, 5, 14, 34, 43, 3, 18, 28, 16]`  
How to do this in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right you have list of strings and want to get list of integers.
This can be easily done by:

```
lst = [int(item) for item in lst]
```

For example:

```
>>> lst = ['1000', '6', '1', '5', '14', '34', '43', '3', '18', '28', '16']
>>> lst
['1000', '6', '1', '5', '14', '34', '43', '3', '18', '28', '16']
>>> lst = [int(item) for item in lst]
>>> lst
[1000, 6, 1, 5, 14, 34, 43, 3, 18, 28, 16]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert each element into an Integer.

```
>>> lst_string = ['1000', '6', '1', '5', '14', '34', '43', '3', '18', '28', '16']
>>> lst_int = [int(n) for n in lst_string]
>>> print lst_int
[1000, 6, 1, 5, 14, 34, 43, 3, 18, 28, 16]
```

Or you can use the `map`-function which performs a **function** on a **sequence**. In this case we perform the `int`-function to your list.

```
>>> map(int, lst_string)
[1000, 6, 1, 5, 14, 34, 43, 3, 18, 28, 16]
```

Comment: I tried your second solution and this is its output:  `>>> map(int, lst_string)
<map object at 0x0214F6D0>`

Comment: You're using python3. In python3 [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns iterator-object, not a list as in python2. So try `list(map(int, lst_string))`